# Custom checkbox without indicator (text)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a custom checkbox without the indicator like this:

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-description"></span>
</label>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/9F1f9nQjl4W96POaF90K?p=preview

As you can see, the checkbox doesn't work. But if you add text:

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-description"> Checkbox</span>
</label>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/1cGDXPCcWqOBQLWRwVdS?p=preview

It works. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace Checkbox name with some html tag, for example: `</p>`.

Comment: It works but it's not a very clean way... first of all there is a space next to the checkbox that becomes clickable. Second it becomes impossible to align without playing with margins/paddings...

Comment: Some html tag instead of that?

Comment: </p> works... please update your answer so I can validate it! thanks and good job!